# Getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError when I create an object of WildcardQuery

Tags: java, lucene

We have recently upgraded from Lucene 3.6 to Lucene 4.7.2, and are facing
issues while creating the object of `WildCardQuery`

`*java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded*`

**Code:**

```
Query query = new WildcardQuery(new Term("id", "someTerm"));
```

**StackTrace:**

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded at
org.apache.lucene.util.automaton.Automaton.clone(Automaton.java:646) at
 org.apache.lucene.util.automaton.SpecialOperations.getCommonSuffixBytesRef(SpecialOperations.java:163) at 
org.apache.lucene.util.automaton.CompiledAutomaton.
(CompiledAutomaton.java:168) at 
org.apache.lucene.util.automaton.CompiledAutomaton.
(CompiledAutomaton.java:91) at
org.apache.lucene.search.AutomatonQuery.(AutomatonQuery.java:67) at 
org.apache.lucene.search.WildcardQuery.(WildcardQuery.java:57)
```

NOTE: Since the search terms are entered by the end user, we are not sure of
what term caused it.

Thanks,
P.

Comment: Put code into code blocks

Comment: If the terms are entered by the end user, they aren't string literals, so you haven't posted the real code that causes the problem. You will just have to find out what the term was. We can't tell you. Does the stack trace really have those trailing periods?